# How to format single line css file?

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using VS 2013 and there is some downloaded css files that have everything packed in 1 line.

How do I get it in proper format?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because they just need to get a different download from http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: that file it's a minified version, you can either download bootstrap and get the original file or look for an online unminify css... for example http://unminify.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D to auto format it. Works for me in VS 2013.

EDIT: Just noticed you're using the "min" version. That's the minified version. There is a 'full' version available where everything is 'correctly' formatted.

Comment: so the "full" version is exactly same as "min" one right?

Comment: Yep they are the same.

full: full code with comments, slightly larger file size but easier to read for devs.

min: filesize slightly smaller but all comments and line breaks are taken out.

Therefore you'll probably get a slightly better performance from the min file but it's much more difficult for a human to read.

Comment: thanks, I use the full/normal version now. I know the Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D for auto format codes but for some reason whenever I do that on single Css files like this one => the VS is not responding... maybe too much work =))

Comment: You're welcome :)

Quite possibly. I think it's Ctrl + K, Ctrl + F if you want to format the code you have highlighted, you could try that to partially format the page but i'd advise using the normal version like you're doing.